# Problem with external data files in pyinstaller-compiled code in python

Tags: python, pyinstaller

So, I have a readme.txt file for my app, and I added a thing where in my program, if I do something, it will print the contents of the readme.txt file. When I compiled my app, I used pyinstaller, and I modified the .spec file to include the the readme.txt, so I can use it when compiled. But here comes the problem: Now, if I start the app by itself, and choose to display the readme file, it gives an error that it can't find the file. But if I start the app the app in cmd, it has no problem showing it. What can I do to make it print the file's contents with no problem, without using cmd on it? (the app is command-line, if it helps. I also didn't use any --onefile when compiling into an .exe, btw I'm on Windows 10)

Edit: Someone requested that I add the "Analysis" section of the .spec file, so here it is:

```py
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\edyal\\Documents\\Programming\\Python\\KhempinKonxhugtoh'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('readme.txt', '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
```

Comment: Plesse add the analysis section of your spec sheet

Comment: @RobertKearns Ok, now?

Comment: It sounds like it's a working directory problem. Import os in your run script and right before you print the readme add ```print(os.getcwd())```.  This will tell you what directory the computer is looking for the file in.